# Is the boundary of the closure of a bounded set $S$ equal to the boundary of $S$?

Tags: general-topology

Is the boundary of the closure of a bounded set $S$ equal to the boundary of $S$?

I know the boundary of the closure of a set $S$ is not always equal to the boundary of $S$:
Let $S:=\mathbb{Q}$.
$\operatorname{Bd}S=\mathbb{R}$.
$\operatorname{Bd}\overline{S}=\operatorname{Bd}\operatorname{\mathbb{R}}=\emptyset$.

I know the boundary of the closure of a set $S$ is a subset of the boundary of $S$.

Comment: Just intersect your example with $[0,1]$.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Let $S:=\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$. Then, $\operatorname{Bd}S=[0,1]$ and $\operatorname{Bd}\overline{S}=\{0,1\}$. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a punctured disk in the plane, or the set  $(-1,0)\cup(0,1)$.

Comment: Yuval Peres, Thank you very much for your answer.